# Why do I get this error "CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bitmap

### Scenario 1)

I'm reading a png file inside documents folder. If I directly read the file from Documents folder, I get the following values.

```
    NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);   => 2000
    NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef); => 2000

    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(imageRef) / 8;    => 8
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef);           => 16000
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef); => 16
```

If I try to create BitmapContext from that,

```
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(imageData,
                                                 width,
                                                 height,
                                                 bitsPerComponent,
                                                 bytesPerRow,
                                                 colorSpace,
                                                 bitmapInfo);
```

It gives ": CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination" and fails.

### Scenario 2)

If I add the same png file to "Assets.xcassets", Then I get the following values

```
    NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);   => 2000
    NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef); => 2000

    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(imageRef) / 8;    => 4
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef);           => 8000
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef); => 8
```

**Then I can create the BitmapContext without any problem.**

Can anybody please help me on this..?
*(I must read the file from documents folder wihtout using "Assets.xcassets")*

Comment: `imageData` being? If you put `NULL` instead?

Comment: @Larme, I use 'imageData' later in the code for a different work :-(